# Cosmos DB succeeds and fails on randomly on the same query, saying they are cross partition when they aren't

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with the partition key "flightConversationId".

I am doing a very simple query, BY THE PARTITON KEY FIELD

`SELECT * from root WHERE root.flightConversationId="b36d13c0-cbec-11e7-a4ad-8fcedf370f98"`

When doing this query via the nodeJS SDK, it will work one second, and fail the next with the error:

`Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception.`

I realize I could enable cross-partition querying, but I do not need cross partition queries. What is going on???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation seemed to resolve itself over time.

My theory is that when we deleted a collection and recreated it with a new partition key, it took a long time for all remnants of the original collection to really be deleted from the cloud, and that some requests were going to the "old" collection that had the same name as the "new".

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly scope the query to a partition by providing an `FeedOptions` or `RequestOptions` class with a `partitionKey` property. Using the PartitionKey in your where clause isn't enough without that explicit scope. This is for C# but should be same object model:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-partition-data

```
Document result = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(
  UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db", "coll", "XMS-001-FE24C"), 
  new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("XMS-0001") });
```

jsDoc:

http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/global.html#RequestOptions
http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/global.html#FeedOptions

Comment: I don't think you are correct, for two reasons. The query works sometimes with no change.
    
From the docs you do not have to provide a partition key when it is part of the query itself. See "Querying partitioned containers" on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-partition-data
    
Your second link indicates you only need to provide the key when querying across partitions (I'm not).
    
Also "When you query data in partitioned containers, CDB automatically routes the query to the partitions corresponding to the partition key values specified in the filter."

Comment: x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition Optional. Must be set to true for any queries that do not filter against a single partition key. Queries that filter against a single partition key value will be executed against only a single partition even if this is set to true.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api

Comment: And if that were true why would it say "or revise your query to avoid this exception"?

Comment: Did you try it? Regardless of the documentation, the suggestion comes from experience querying partitioned collections with the partition key in the where clause. Add PartitionKey, success. No PartitionKey, get a nastygram about cross partition queries. YMMV.

Comment: I'd like to get to the root of the issue, but thanks. If it is needlessly doing cross partition, then it is also charging you more.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It should be the correct answer regardless of whether the the 'x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition must be enabled' error is still occurring. One suggestion would be to try both the queryDocuments and the readDocuments client methods. The latter might be a helpful indicator as for what the expected PK should be. And yes, enablecrosspartition should be off if you already know the PK. Having it on is a bit more expensive, so best not to use unless it's completely necessary.